# Why is my Hunter being lazy?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Just to clarify my Hunter hunts, he has ammo, he has weapons. My question is **why does my hunter not hunt for long periods of time**? I really dont ever see him kill anything, i just check out his kill count occasionally to see what he has been up to. Most of the time i just see him sitting around with "No Job." Is there a way to get him to continously hunt unless he needs to eat/drink. The wiki says a hunter will usually stay outside for the majority of the time such is not true of my hunter.

Comment: Please stop adding Tags into the title, that's what the tags are for. A better title would be "Why does my hunter not hunt for a longer time?" or "Why does my hunter make loooong breaks?".

Comment: A tag in the title tends to get more attention from google browsers which in turn brings more publicity to this site, so im sorry but I see no reason to stop.

Comment: [Should questions contain "tags" in their title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) ... or the short version, no, not really.

Comment: @Paralytic The tag is automatically added to the title for Google.  You really don't need to add it yourself.  Try googling "dwarf fortress roof cave" for an example.

Comment: @Bobby i know when to admit i'm wrong, titles shall be fixed, your initial comment before you edited it made it sound as if it just annoyed you and wanted it removed so as to apease(sp?) you

Comment: Yeah, that comment could have been a lot better worded in the first place. But

Comment: Have you checked for animals on the map?

Comment: there are always a few ravens about @sciguy1121

Comment: Ravens are generally too small to be butchered, that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue may be that there just aren't many butcher-able animals around (ravens are too small). If there are, and your hunters still don't do anything, close the game and open it again, sometimes that helps.

Comment: PROTIP: have your military kill the ravens to make way for larger, meatier animals.

Comment: @kotekzot thanks for that, i tried once but gave up as they move very fast and hide most of the time so finding them was a pain

Comment: You can zoom to any living creature on the map by using the unit menu. Give your military a kill order and they'll handle the rest. Make sure they have ranged weapons though.

Comment: It seems once my hunters are put into a squad they wont hunt is this just one of those things?